# Change installation directory for Kindle on PC?

Tags: windows, kindle

My C: drive is a solid state drive intended only for my OS.

I downloaded the Kindle app installer to my D: drive, and when I open the installer, it just installs it straight to my C: drive, without giving me the option of installing it elsewhere.

Is it possible to change the installation directory of Kindle for PC?

Comment: Try moving the installation files and see what happens